# Html Forms Not Sending

Tags: html, forms

I'm the developer on a Minecraft server. I know a lot about programming in HTML but not everything.

I'm making a application form for the server but I'm not sure how to save or send it off. Here is the code for the forms I have so far

```
<center>
    <form action="MAILTO:email@gmial.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <font color="white">Ign:</font><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="your email"><br>
        <font color="white">Skype:</font><br>
        <input type="text" name="NewPassword"><br>
        <font color="white">Why do you think you should have this rank?</font><br>
        <input type="text" name="Repeat" size="50"><br>
        <font color="white">Rank:</font><br>
        <input type="text" name="OldPassword" ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</center>
```

But when anyone but me tries to hit "Submit" It does absolutely nothing. If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or a better method of doing it I would be grateful.

Any other information you need can be provided

Comment: You're not closing the `<form>` tag. Additionally, `center` and `font` tags are depreciated.

Comment: Thank you ill see if changing that will help

Comment: Is there any way for me to send it without them having to open their mail provider?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to look into a server-side language like `PHP`, `.Net` etc.

Comment: The html form doesn't work that way, you will need to incorporate with php as well. The reason it is not working is because your action you set to "MAILTO:email@gmial.com". You should be redirect to something like "form-handling.php" where the form will be processed and sent off. You can refer to this tutorial on how to create a proper form
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an ending `<form>` tag, also in your `action=""` attribute it is to `email@gmial.com` when it should be `email@gmail.com`, and last the `<font>` tag is outdated and you should use CSS instead.